# be intended to vs intend to

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I see a lot of examples of *be intended to* and *intend to*. Both of them mean ***plan to do***.

Some examples:

> Selling was my game and I **intended to** be a winner.
>
> The ban **is intended to** be permanent.

I guess the difference between them is if the subject is human, it should use **be intended to**. Otherwise use **intend to**. Is that right?

Comment: "if the subject is human" what makes you think so?

Comment: Logically, intending can only be done by an living being. A stone cannot "intend" to do something, right? It's not about grammar as such. The ban did not intend, but someone intended that the ban ought to **be or do** something. HTH.

Comment: @Kris, I understood it now , Actually I want to say the subject is an living being like human . Thanks your nice comments. :)

Comment: Isn't this just an active versus passive voice difference?

Comment: Oh..I didn't thought that.

Comment: @Barmar No, it has to do with the kind of verb.

Comment: Then it's whether the thing the intentions refer to is the subject or object. _I intended to be_ == subject, _is intended to be_ = object.

Comment: @Barmar In *Bob is intended to be...*, Bob is the subject!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions exist but have different uses. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intend#:%7E:text=If%20you%20intend%20to%20do,or%20planned%20to%20do%20it.&text=If%20something%20is%20intended%20for,affect%20them%20in%20some%20way.) explains

> If you ***intend*** to do something, *you have decided or planned to do it*.
>
> - She ***intends*** to do A levels and go to university.
>
> If something ***is intended*** for a particular purpose, *it has been planned to fulfil that purpose*. If something is intended for a particular person, it has been planned to be used by that person or to affect them in some way.
>
> - This money ***is intended for*** the development of the tourist industry.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-intended-for) records the phrase ***be intended*** with the preposition ***for***:

> to be made, done, or said for a particular purpose or person
>
> - The posts are ***intended for*** students who have recently completed a first degree in biology.

I personally see ***intended*** as a synonym of ***meant***, and it can be used with **for + noun** or **to + verb**, as you can see in this [FDA article](https://www.fda.gov/food/information-consumers-using-dietary-supplements/questions-and-answers-dietary-supplements):

> A dietary supplement is a product ***intended for*** ingestion that, among other requirements, contains a "dietary ingredient" ***intended to*** supplement the diet.

The intending is done by an animate subject in both cases. The difficulty is with the phrase ***be intended for/to do smth***.
Although Macmillan says that ***something*** can be intended for something else, I don't see why you cannot say

> He ***is intended to*** represent the distillation of the standards expected by those who regularly use the market. ([source](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/8/notes))

However, examples such as this last one are more rare and formal, and sound rather the synonym of ***is meant/expected/supposed to***.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20intends%20to%2Che%20is%20intended%20to%2Che%20intended%20to%2C%20he%20was%20intended%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20intends%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20intends%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20intended%20to%3B%2Cc0) confirms it
[image]

The conclusion is that if you want to express someone's intention concerning themselves, use ***intend to***:

> I *intend* to study <sub>[am thinking of studying]</sub> cooking this summer.

If someone has an intention, but it is directed at something or someone else *which functions as the **subject** of your sentence*, then use ***be intended to***:

> Students ***are intended to study*** cooking this summer <sub>[e.g. by the university]</sub>.

The reference to passive voice in the comments was not out of place. Consider:

> God ***intended man to be*** the king of creation. (active)
> Man ***was intended*** (by God) ***to be*** the king of creation. (passive)

Answer (score -2):

"Is intended to" means someone has intentions for something other than themself. "Say hello to Fred, everyone. He's intended to fill the position Jack occupied before his retirement. I intended to tell you about him last week, but I forgot."

Comment: See my comment at OP. HTH.